# How can i get a Spring managed SessionCustomizer into the EclipseLink Config

Tags: spring, eclipselink, spring-orm

I'm working with eclipselink in a spring project. one necessary part of my configuration is a SessionCustomizer that configures my id-generator (Snowflake by twitter).

**Is it possible to handle the creation of this customizer with spring so i can use dependency injection and use property-placeholders?**

The only examples i found for Customizers always configure the class in the persistence xml.

Here is my config so far:

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="platform.auth-service" />
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter" ref="jpaVendorAdapter" />
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jPAPropertyProviderMap" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
    <property name="generateDdl" value="${database.generateTables}" />
    <property name="databasePlatform" value="${database.platform}" />
</bean>
<bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
<bean id="jpaDialect" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaDialect" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the `@Configurable` Annotation from spring-aop (AspectJ integration) would have been a solution i decided to solve my problem with a static `SequenceHolder` class where i store the sequences with a `SequenceInstaller` bean.

Finally the `SessionCustomizer` installs the stored sequences in the persistencecontextfactory.

I had to configure a dependency between the factory and the installer because spring might have handled the factory before the installer otherwise.